# Google app engine - deploy web app with Javascript -> Ajax GET -> PHP

Tags: php, html, google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-apps

I am deploying a static website to google app engine. It has a PHP file that sends mail - part of contact us form. When I am deploying in other hosting service  providers then it works i.e. javascript in contact us form can call php file as GET ajax call and PHP file sends mail.  However when I am deploying it with google app engine, the php scripts not recognized. The response from PHP file is simply php scripts

My app.yaml file

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
#threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)

# Serve php scripts.
- url: /mail/(.*)
  script: /mail/\1.php  # specify a script
```

```
Response from php file
isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP $mail->Host = 'smtp.dummy.com';
```

Content of php file

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$name = $_GET['name'];
$visitor_email = $_GET['email'];
$phone = $_GET['phone'];
$subject = $_GET['subject'];
$message = $_GET['message'];
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.dummy.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;    
...
...
```

Comment: What do you mean static?

Comment: You should probably tag it with Google App if that is what you have problem with.